# Android: NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets sending email on SDK 18

Tags: java, android, email, character-encoding, sdk

My app is currently sending emails through normal SMTP access and it's working fine in SDK 19+ devices, but having problems in my Asus Android 4.3 SDK 18 with the error described in title.

The weird thing is I'm not using StandardCharsets.UTF_8 but instead the literal "UTF-8" and makes no difference

I'm not planning to go into Gmail API yet as I'm not in the mood of "fighting" implementing oAuth authentication, so I'm trying to find some simple fix for what I already have.

Below is the code I'm using, and it makes no difference whether I use the "UTF-8" parameter or not. Always the same error in the Transport.Send line.

Any ideas to make it to work in SDK 18- devices guys?

```
public static String send(String jsonEmail)
{
    String result = Enum.Result.OK;

    AppSettings appSettings = AppSettings.getInstance();

    JSONObject oJsonEmail = TMJson.str2JSON(jsonEmail);

    try {
        String subject = oJsonEmail.getString("subject");
        String message = oJsonEmail.getString("message");
        String sendTo = oJsonEmail.getString("send_to");
        String smtpServer = oJsonEmail.getString("smtp_server");
        String smtpPort = oJsonEmail.getString("smtp_port");
        String smtpUseAuth = oJsonEmail.getString("smtp_useauth");
        boolean centerBodyText = Boolean.parseBoolean(oJsonEmail.getString("center_text"));

        final String smtpUser = oJsonEmail.getString("smtp_user");
        final String smtpPass = oJsonEmail.getString("smtp_pass");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpUseAuth);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.from.alias", "My App Name");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUser, smtpPass);
                    }
                });

        message = TMJson.decodeEmail(message);
        message = format(message, centerBodyText);

        Message oMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        oMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(appSettings.emailFrom),
                session.getProperty("mail.from.alias"), "UTF-8"));
        oMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(sendTo));
        oMessage.setSubject(subject);
        oMessage.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-2");

        Transport.send(oMessage);
    }catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
        result = Enum.Result.KO;
        ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Complete logcat:

```
05-06 15:45:29.152 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:29.152 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:34.282 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:34.282 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:37.552 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:37.552 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:40.542 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:40.542 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-06 15:45:52.962 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1600: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.getActiveNetwork ()Landroid/net/Network;
05-06 15:45:52.992 12519-12519/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 5083: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
05-06 15:46:21.152 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: method Lcom/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore;.getSession incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Ljavax/mail/Service;
05-06 15:46:21.152 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: method Lcom/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Store;.getSession incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Ljavax/mail/Service;
05-06 15:46:21.152 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.162 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.182 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.182 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41922 (ISO_8859_1) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.212 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 56512: Ljavax/activation/ActivationDataFlavor;.equals (Ljava/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor;)Z
05-06 15:46:21.212 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor;)
05-06 15:46:21.232 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.232 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.242 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.242 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.242 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.242 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:21.312 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 41924 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
05-06 15:46:23.252 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm: threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42f05500)
05-06 15:46:23.252 12519-12898/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-7-thread-1
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$LoginAuthenticator.doAuth(SMTPTransport.java:979)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:924)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
        at com.xxx.xxx.helpers.TMEmail.send(TMEmail.java:78)
        at com.xxx.xxx.activities.authentication.SendEmailTask.call(LoginActivity.java:876)
        at com.xxx.xxx.activities.authentication.SendEmailTask.call(LoginActivity.java:864)
        at com.xxx.xxx.helpers.TaskRunner.lambda$executeAsync$1$TaskRunner(TaskRunner.java:23)
        at com.xxx.xxx.helpers.-$$Lambda$TaskRunner$S0wtc4khwtgNrHwkXyPnQb3di8w.run(lambda)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Gradle:

```
api 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.4'
api 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's time to answer my own question (very quickly though, but I'm very restless and kept on researching).

The fix was as simple as lowering "com.sun.mail:android-mail" and "com.sun.mail:android-activation" to the max version which doesn't use "java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets", which is 1.5.5

```
api 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
api 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but it works, so I'll marke it as correct.